# jquery onclick show image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a cart of images, that I would like to show up one by one in the bag when clicked (Click on the first two). It seems the script I am using only works with one image, not a series of images. Is there an easier way to create this effect?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_image()
{
      var img = document.createElement("img");
    document.getElementById("shampoo").style.display="block";  


}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function show_image()
{


    document.getElementById("spray2").style.display="block";  

}
</script>
```

The HTML

```
<div class="clearfix" id="page">
<div class="title"><img src="assets/yourbag.png" width="296" height="112" alt=""/></div>
<div class="bag"><img src="assets/bag.png" width="472" height="285" alt=""/></div> 
<div class="leftpocket"><img src="assets/pocket_left.png" width="209" height="159" alt=""/></div>
<div class="rightpocket"><img src="assets/pocket_right.png" width="209" height="155" alt=""/></div>
 <div id="shampoo" style="display:none"><img src="assets/bottle.png" width="86" height="206" alt="" id="shampoo"/></div>



<div class="product1">  <input type="button" name="show" id="show" onclick="show_image()"  /></div>
 <div id="spray2" style="display:none"><img src="assets/spraycan.png" width="86" height="206" alt="" id="spray2"/></div>

<div class="product2"> <input type="button" name="spray" id="spray" onclick="show_image()"  /></div>
<div class="product3"><img src="assets/tissues.png" width="73" height="97" alt=""/></div>
<div class="product4"><img src="assets/tp.png" width="90" height="105" alt=""/></div>

<div class="product5"><img src="assets/detergent.png" width="61" height="120" alt=""/></div>
<div class="product6"><img src="assets/laundrypods.png" width="124" height="83" alt=""/></div>
<div class="product7"><img src="assets/sunscreen.png" width="58" height="127" alt=""/></div>
<div class="product8"><img src="assets/babyshapoo.png" width="51" height="119" alt=""/></div>

<div class="product9"><img src="assets/diapers.png" width="74" height="115" alt=""/></div>
<div class="more"></div>
<div class="trade"></div>
```

Comment: Check the id of the currently clicked image, using the keyword this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I believe my id's are correct.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you click an image, you want to add that clicked image to the bag/cart thing?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to happen Azeirah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/BwjQj/4/

The blue section is your "bag".

add your `<img>` into the `<div>`'s with the class `item` and it should work fine. Do you also want to be able to remove them from the cart?

Comment: Well when I click on the first one the image for the second one seems to show up, so something is happening, but the script is triggering wrong.

Comment: The reason an image shows up the first time is because the div `shampoo` already has an image in it. `style.display = block` makes that div visible. If you want to add more images to `shampoo` through javascript, you'll need to do it this way.

Comment: I don't want to add more images to the shampoo div, I want one image associated with each current image on the page, to show up when clicked.

Comment: Alright, I think I know what you mean, but the code you've written won't do that at all. I'll update my post in a few minutes.

Comment: It is certainly closer to what I need. I do need the image to stay at the bottom, even though it is duplicated into the cart. But an option to remove it would be amazing as well!

Comment: Peice of cake! updated again, here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/BwjQj/4/ Click on the items in the cart to remove them.

Comment: Scott, it seems the onload function isnt working on my page, even though I added the script in between the tags. Any suggestions?

Comment: Here's the same code with onload used: http://jsfiddle.net/BwjQj/5/ ..I'm just not sure what you're trying to do with onload!

Answer (score 0):

Scott Rowell already did this for you, but I had already been developing a version when I saw his answer.  See if you like my try:

HTML:

```
<div id="bag1" class='bag'></div>
<div class='prods'>
    <img id="prod1" class="prod" src="http://www.sanbarcomputing.com/images/html5-logo.png"></img>
    <img id="prod2" class="prod" src="http://www.sanbarcomputing.com/images/js.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var prod1Elem = document.getElementById('prod1'),
    prod2Elem = document.getElementById('prod2'),
    bag1Elem = document.getElementById('bag1');

function add() {
    var item = this.cloneNode();
    item.className = item.id + 'Items';
    bag1Elem.appendChild(item);
    item.addEventListener('click', del, false);
}

function del() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}

prod1.addEventListener('click', add, false);
prod2.addEventListener('click', add, false);
```

CSS:

```
div.prods {
    text-align: center;
}
div.bag {
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 70px;
}
img.prod {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
img.prod1Items {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
img.prod2Items {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aeoril/dyeam/)

Comment: I tried this method and couldn't get it to work. Any thoughts as to why? I reuploaded to the original link

Comment: It worked for me in the Fiddle. Just not when copy and pasted into my own code. I tried on firefox, safari, and chrome.

Comment: @user2711818 view the source here for how I got it working:  http://www.sanbarcomputing.com/flat/forumPosts/src/cart/cart.html you can view the javascript source files using the debugging tools in Chrome, Firefox, etc. (F12 in Chrome, then the *Sources* tab).  If I use the document.onload event it does not work, but window.onload does work